# call webservice asynchronously for nos of attempt

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, asynchronous

I need to consume webservice asynchronously. But in such a manner that if the called method is not complete in 7 second, it should call again till N attempts. And the UI also should not hang.

How to do this??

Comment: What kind of web service? How is the proxy generated? Can you use Task and async/await? Can you provide some code to start with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this via Background process and use of timer.

I am not going to explain how to use this, however will provide you link for background process

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

You will need to implement the dummy solution and then use it in your application.

Here is the sample solution
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/backgroundworker-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: thanks, i need to do it asynchronously. Since I have to call multiple webmethods. So  how can I achieve this in Background Worker.